# To print elements of Link List in c++ (See Code)

Tags: c++

My problem is that I'm trying to make a program that would make nodes (of a link list) dynamically. Everything goes fine but when at the bottom I try to print the elements of link list using the while loop as: `while(ptr->next !=NULL)`,the program only prints the first element. 
(Yes I have mentioned `ptr=ptr->next` inside my loop)
Here is my CODE:

```
struct node {
    int item;
    node *next;
}
;
main() {
    int a,b,c=0;
    node *head,*tail,*ptr, *temp;
    ptr = new node;
    ptr->item = 0;
    ptr->next = NULL;
    head= ptr;
    ptr->next=tail;
    for (int i=0;1;i++) {
        cout<<" Enter 1 if u want to make another node\n Enter 2 to stop making nodes\n";
        cin>>a;
        if(a==1) {
            if(c!=0) {
                ptr = new node;
                cout<<"Enter new element at the new node:\n";
                cin>>b;
                ptr->item = b;
                ptr->next = NULL;
                tail = ptr;
            }
            if(c==0) {
                ptr = new node;
                cout<<"Enter new element at the new node:\n";
                cin>>b;
                ptr->item = b;
                head->next= ptr;
                ptr->next = NULL;
                tail = ptr;
                c++;
            }
        } else if(a==2) {
            break;
        }
    }
    ptr=head;
    while(ptr->next != NULL) {
        ptr=ptr->next;
        cout<<" element: "<<ptr->item<<endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: Stepping through with your debugger would clarify lot of things! Asking such on Stack Overflow is off-topic.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I'm a beginner of data structures. Proper help would be appreciated.

Comment: Well, recommending to use your debugger is helpful in 1st place. Learn how to use it, that's an essential skill.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I have little knowledge of using a debugger.

Comment: As mentioned it's essential. Learn how to use it. It's not that hard after all.

Comment: The biggest suggestion for a new programmer to data structures is to actually grab a pencil and paper and draw out what your code is really doing. Not what you thing it should be doing, line-by-line, what your code does. I told many of my students this as a TA and it helped many of them. Drawing this out would show you are not setting the tail's next pointer correctly. Your code is also more complicated than necessary as the answer below states.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You initially want to set the tail to the same node as the head.  This is because you want to append elements to the tail element, regardless of where the head is.  That also gets rid of the complexity of counting whether you've added a node or not (variable `c`) and eliminates the conditional branching (of which the code was very similar: see [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself))

The process for adding an element to the tail of a linked list is:

1. Populate the new element, setting its `next` to `NULL`.
2. Point the tail element's next to this new element.
3. Set the new element as the tail.

Try using this

```
struct node {
    int item;
    node *next;
};
main() {
    int input;
    node *head,*tail,*ptr;
    ptr = new node;
    ptr->item = 0;
    ptr->next = NULL;
    head = ptr;
    tail = ptr;
    while(true) {
        cout<<" Enter 1 if u want to make another node\n Enter 2 to stop making nodes\n";
        cin>>input;
        cin.clear();
        if(input==1) {
            ptr = new node;
            cout<<"Enter new element at the new node:\n";
            cin>>input;
            cin.clear();
            ptr->item = input;
            tail->next= ptr;
            ptr->next = NULL;
            tail = ptr;
        } else if(input==2) {
            break;
        }
    }
    ptr=head;
    while(ptr->next != NULL) {
        ptr=ptr->next;
        cout<<" element: "<<ptr->item<<endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: Ohh! Thanks a bunch.. I knew about that instance somehow didn't remember to apply. Thanks alot that solves my problem.

Answer (score 1):

Already my compiler (g++ 4.8 with flags -Wall -Wextra -pedantic) solves the problem:

```
warning: ‘tail’ is used uninitialized in this function [-Wuninitialized]
```

You are updating next, but with an uninitialized variable tail.

Comment: That's a very good answer for a badly asked question, in contrary to the accepted one. Just fixing the OPs code, will have little to none real teaching/learning effects. Keep on this way please!

Comment: Thanks for the encouragement!